# Could not install EntityFramework 6.1.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and windows 10.
I created a new web project (MVC) with no authentication, I Tried to install EntityFramework 6.1.3 with this command in package manager "Install-Package EntityFramewor" but I got this error :

> Type 'get-help EntityFramework' to see all available Entity Framework
>   commands. Package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' does not exist in folder
>   'C:\Projects\WebApplication1\packages' Install-Package : Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.3
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

I can install EntityFramework 6.1.2 without any problem.

Comment: it looks like there's a typo in your command. Did you try `install-package EntityFramework` ?

Comment: No, if you look at the error I don't have typo error... I just missed a "k" in the question

Comment: `Install-Package EntityFramework`

Answer (score 1):

using manage Nuget package install entityframework 6.1.2 then update it to 6.1.3.